# Copy row to another sheet in excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

First off, I have never used VBA (or VB for that matter), so keep that in mind. I am trying to copy a row to another sheet in my workbook. So whenever any change in row 2 will happen in sheet1, that row should be copied in row 2 on sheet2. If row 3 is modified in sheet1, row 5 should be modified on sheet2. I want there to be an empty row between each row on sheet2. I am going to try and create a new table with VBA to place inside this empty row. Anyways, I am getting an error on my Selection.Paste line. I have very limited knowledge (an hours worth) on VBA, so I could be completely off on what I am trying to do.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 'Do not worry about column headers
  If Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub

  'On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  Application.EnableEvents = False 'This might be necessary?

  Sheet1.Rows(Target.Row).Select
  Selection.Copy
  Sheet1.Rows(Target.Row).Copy

  If Target.Row = 2 Then
    Sheet2.Rows(Target.Row).Select
    Selection.Paste
  Else
    Sheet2.Select
    Sheet2.Rows(Target.Row + Target.Row - 1).Select
    Selection.Paste
  End If

ErrHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True 'This might be necessary?
End Sub
```

---

**Edit:** After changing `Selection.Paste` to `ActiveSheet.Paste`, it is now working.

Comment: What error are you getting on the `Selection.Paste` line?

Comment: Ah, I got it working now -_-. I changed `Selection.Paste` to `ActiveSheet.Paste`

Comment: @Justin, please set your own question to answered if you got it to work.

Comment: @Gimp, Is there a way to do that other than providing an answer response?

Comment: Note - this will not work as you want if someone updates more than one row at once: only the first affected row will be copied...

Comment: @TimWilliams: Very true.

Comment: @Justin you should be able to check your own question as the answer.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: added dealing with multi-area selections

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim a As Range, rw As Range
    For Each a In Selection.Areas
        For Each rw In a.Rows
            If rw.Row >= 2 Then
                rw.EntireRow.Copy Sheet2.Cells(2 + (rw.Row - 2) * 3, 1)
            End If
        Next rw
    Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: Quite a bit more compact than my implementation :)

Comment: Note this only handles a contiguous area - if it's possible that users will update multiple non-contiguous cells then you'll need to loop through each range in `Selection.Areas` and then though the rows in each area.

Comment: + 1 for a better answer which not only solves the current problem but also helps the asker in what he was initially trying to achieve:)