# copy row to next free row on another spreadsheet on change

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

First off, I'm a noob when it comes to Macros and VBA, so please forgive me if I don't make sense.

I've got an Excel spreadsheet which is basically a list of users and their mobile phone numbers and some other bits (columns A-K are currently used) and it's ordered by rows.

What I need is a way of copying the whole row if I change a cell. So if I change the username, it copies the whole row of that user to the next blank row on a second sheet.

The purpose of this is to keep an audit trail allowing us to see who's previously used a number etc.

I found this: [Copy row to another sheet in excel using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400369/copy-row-to-another-sheet-in-excel-using-vba) which is working as intended, but I can't for the life of me get it to a, copy the cells to the next free row, or b, not overwrite the existing entry.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim a As Range, rw As Range
For Each a In Selection.Areas
    For Each rw In a.Rows
        If rw.Row >= 2 Then
            rw.EntireRow.Copy Sheet2.Cells(2 + (rw.Row - 2) * 3, 1)
        End If
    Next rw
Next a
End Sub
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me customise it.

I'm using Excel 2010 on Win7.

Many thank in advance.

Comment: What is you clear (aka delete/remove/blank out) hte username? What column is the username?

Comment: Could you describe what the destination cell on Sheet2 is intended to be?

Answer (score 1):

Typically the [Intersect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195772(v=office.11).aspx) is used to determine if the cell or cells receiving a change involve one or more columns that you are concerned with. You can add additional parameters; in this case, I've [.Offset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) down one row to make sure that row 1 is not involved.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'not really necessary in this case but never a bad idea within a Worksheet_Change
        Dim a As Range
        For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns(1), Me.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0))
            If CBool(Len(a.Value2)) Then _
                a.EntireRow.Copy _
                    Destination:=Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)  'not really sure this is the correct destination
        Next a
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I've included a call to disable event handling for the duration of the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro. While this is a critical step when the Worksheet_Change modifies values, it is not really important to incorporate here. However, it does not harm and is already in place in case you want to augment the Worksheet_Change to include something like a timestamp that would change the values on the worksheet.

Comment: The destination is perfect, it's adding a new line each time. Is there any way we can avoid it looking for change in just column 1? I'd like it to look for changes anywhere in columns A to K, and then copy the whole thing across. So if someone puts a note in K, it'll copy the whole row again, or if someone puts a new number in C.

Comment: The thing to watch out for here is a large copy paste. **Target** is not always a single cell; it can be a number of cells so if someone pasted some values into A5:E5 you wouldn't want 5 copies of row 5 pasted across. I may come up with something in a bit. I know I've posted a solution to the rows problem into these forums a while back.

Comment: I see your point. That would create a monster of a spreadsheet. I'll do some independent searching and see if I can find anything useful. Thanks again.